# Can't figure out what is missing after cloning Laravel site on webserver

Tags: laravel, git, laravel-5, gitignore

Using GIT I have built a Laravel site, which among other things uses Laravel File Manager. Locally everything works and when I just transfer ALL files manualy with FileZilla to a folder on my webserver, it also works just fine. All routes that use Laravel Filemanager works fine and there are no problems.

BUT, when I navigate to another folder in my webserver and clone the github repo (which is up-to-date), on the same folder level, everything still works EXCEPT for Laravel Filemanager. When I try to upload an image, for example, I get an "Object not found" and a 404 messsage.

So the only thing that differs is that in the latter case I am using GIT (which is what I want to do, not just keeping track of all changes on my own and transfer files manually). So the conclusion would be that something is left out by .gitignore, that shouldn't be left out. But this is the .gitignore file:

```
/public/hot
/public/photos
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/.idea
/.vscode
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
.env
```

I manually transferred the public/photo and the public/storage folders and files. I have also cleared routes and config cache whithout any luck. I have spent hours comparing files and folders between the three sites (locally, and the two remote sites) trying to figure out why Laravel Filemanager is not found in just the one using GIT.

Can anyone help?

EDITED: To clarify, all photos exists in the public/photos folder and they are showing as they should. It's the application Laravel Filemanager that is not found. Looking at the URL in the FileManager window I can see that it tries to find it on the root level, but in the 2 working sites this URL looks in the public folder. All .htaccess files are identical though between sites...

Answer (score 0):

Have change your url of `.env` files `APP_URL='http://'*********/public/"`?

please try and also run `php artisan config:clear` and php artisan `cache:clear`

Comment: Tried that too. Also the manually uploaded remote site works fine and the .env files are identical between the 2 remote sites.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out... in case anyone else has the same problem.
Row 7 of the file /vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/public/js/lfm.js:

```
var route_prefix = (options && options.prefix) ? options.prefix : '/laravel-filemanager';
```

In my case I had to change the path to '/mysite/public/laravel-filemanager'. After that it worked :-).